# Inventory System Issue: [The items are not correctly placed in the inventory. ] - [Unity- C#]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create an inventory system. I have three scripts: Player, GroundItem, and ItemObject. The Player script adds objects I collide with to the inventory. The GroundItem script is attached to the objects in the game world, and the ItemObject scriptable object holds the properties of the item. The issue I'm facing is that when I collect a fourth item, even if it's stackable, it places it in a different slot.

```
[Header("Inventory")]
public int inventoryMax;
public List<ItemObject> inventory = new List<ItemObject>();

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.CompareTag("GroundItem"))
        {
            if (inventory.Count < inventoryMax)
            {
                if (collision.GetComponent<GroundItem>().item.stackable && inventory.Count > 0)
                {
                    bool addedToStack = false;
                    Debug.Log("1");
                    for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Debug.Log(collision.GetComponent<GroundItem>().item.itemName);
                        if (inventory[i].itemName == collision.GetComponent<GroundItem>().item.itemName)
                        {
                            Debug.Log("2");
                            inventory[i].amount += collision.GetComponent<GroundItem>().item.amount;
                            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
                            addedToStack = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        if(!addedToStack)
                        {
                            Debug.Log("3");
                            inventory.Add(collision.GetComponent<GroundItem>().item);
                            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if(inventory.Count <= 0)
                {
                    Debug.Log("4");
                    inventory.Add(collision.GetComponent<GroundItem>().item);
                    Destroy(collision.gameObject);
                }          
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Inventory is Full");
            }
       
        }
    }
```

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName ="NewItem", menuName ="Items/Item")]
public class ItemObject : ScriptableObject
{
    public string itemName;
    public Sprite itemSprite;
    public int amount;
    public bool stackable;

}
```

```
public class GroundItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ItemObject item;

    public SpriteRenderer groundItemSpriteRenderer;
    public TextMeshPro groundItemAmountText;

    private void Start()
    {
        groundItemAmountText.SetText(item.amount.ToString());
        groundItemSpriteRenderer.sprite = item.itemSprite;
    }


}
```

1- When I check with debug logs, I get the following results: When I collect the first item, it shows 4, which is correct because the inventory is empty initially and it doesn't enter the first condition (if (collision.GetComponent().item.stackable && inventory.Count > 0)).

2- When I collect the second item of the same type, it shows 1-2, which is correct because (inventory[i].itemName == collision.GetComponent().item.itemName) condition is met.

3- When I collect the third item (of a different type), it shows 1-3, which is correct because the (inventory[i].itemName == collision.GetComponent().item.itemName) condition is not met.

4- However, when I collect the fourth item, it again shows 1-3. What could be the reason for this?

I hope I've explained it well. These are the messages I received when I checked with debug logs. Thank you.

Comment: because unless the name matches your first inventory item, its going to be !addedtostack and dumped in a new slot immediately then broken out of the loop..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core issue is that you're testing `!addedToStack` inside the loop that looks for existing stacks to add to. This means that if it's not the first item in the inventory then stacking fails and it appends to the inventory instead of continuing the search.

More broadly, there's a lot of redundant paths, repeated calls to `collision.GetComponent<>()`, duplicated code and so on.

The purpose of this method seems to be: when you enter a tile/area that contains a "GroundItem" object, try to add that to inventory either by adding to an existing stack or appending to the inventory collection. If added, destroy the item in the game world. If not, report that the inventory is full.

Let's implement it as close to that description as we can.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    // Check if there's an item to pick up
    if (!collision.CompareTag("GroundItem"))
        return;
    
    // Get a copy of the picked up item to work with.
    var pickingUp = collision.GetComponent<GroundItem>().item;
    bool added = false;
    
    // Try to add to existing stack
    if (pickingUp.stackable && inventory.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Count && !added; i++)
        {
            if (inventory[i].itemName == pickingUp.itemName)
            {
                // Add amount to existing stack
                Debug.Log($"Adding {pickingUp.amount}x {pickingUp.itemName} to existing stack in inventory slot #{i}.");
                inventory[i].amount += pickingUp.amount;
                added = true;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Not stackable or new item, add to inventory
    if (!added && inventory.Count < inventoryMax)
    {
        // Add to the end of the inventory.
        Debug.Log($"Adding new {(pickingUp.stackable ? $"stack of {pickingUp.amount}x " : "")}{pickingUp.itemName} to inventory in slot #{inventory.Count}.");
        inventory.Add(pickingUp);
        added = true;
    }
    
    // Final disposition of the game object.
    if (added)
        // We picked it up, remove it from the game world.
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
    else
        // Didn't pick it up, leave it and report failure.
        Debug.Log($"Inventory is full, leaving {(pickingUp.stackable ? $"{pickingUp.amount}x " : "")}{pickingUp.itemName}.");
}
```

Doing it this way makes it simpler to read, even if I hadn't peppered it with comments. Each `if` statement is now fairly self-contained, and follows the logical structure of the description I wrote above. (Also, fewer indents improve readability somewhat as well IMO.)

To demonstrate, here's the output from a quick test I did adding various items to an inventory limited to 3 slots:

> Adding new stack of 5x Potion to inventory in slot #0.
> Adding new stack of 2x Scroll to inventory in slot #1.
> Adding new Sword to inventory in slot #2.
> Adding 2x Scroll to existing stack in inventory slot #1.
> Inventory is full, leaving Shield.
> Inventory is full, leaving 10x Berry.
> Adding 2x Potion to existing stack in inventory slot #0.

---

If I were implementing this I'd probably create an `Inventory` class that can be attached as a component of the `Player`. When you're processing collisions on the player you can detect when the collision includes a potential pickup and hand it off to the inventory. This isolates all of the inventory management tasks to the `Inventory` class.

Something like this (but adjusted to Unity of course):

```
class Inventory
{
    private readonly List<ItemObject> _items = new();
    
    // Allow for resizable inventory
    public int Size { get; private set; }
    
    // Access to the item list from outside, for display and so on.
    public IReadOnlyList<ItemObject> Items => _items;
    
    public Inventory(int size)
    {
        Size = size;
    }
    
    // Add an item to the inventory, stacking as necessary.
    public bool TryAddItem(ItemObject item)
    {
        // Locate compatible stack
        if (item.stackable)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (_items[i].itemName == item.itemName)
                {
                    Debug.Log($"> Adding {item.amount}x {item.itemName} to existing stack at #{i}.");
                    _items[i].amount += item.amount;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        
        // Check if we have any free slots
        if (_items.Count >= Size)
        {
            Debug.Log($"> Inventory full, cannot add {(item.stackable ? $"{item.amount}x " : "")}{item.itemName}.");
            return false;
        }
        
        // Append to inventory.
        Debug.Log($"> Adding new {(item.stackable ? $"stack of {item.amount}x " : "")}{item.itemName} to inventory at #{_items.Count}.");
        _items.Add(item);
        return true;
    }
    
    // Remove an item (or multiple items from stack) by name.
    public bool RemoveItem(string itemName, int count = 1)
    {
        // Find first matching item in inventory.
        if (_items.Find(item => item.itemName == itemName) is ItemObject item)
            return RemoveItem(item, count);
        Debug.Log($"No {itemName} found in inventory.");
        return false;
    }
    
    // Remove one or more of an item from the inventory.
    public bool RemoveItem(ItemObject item, int count = 1)
    {
        // Locate item in inventory.
        int index = _items.IndexOf(item);
        if (index == -1)
        {
            Debug.Log($"Item not found in inventory.");
            return false;
        }
        
        // Handle removing partial stacks.
        if (item.stackable)
        {
            if (item.amount < count)
            {
                Debug.Log($"Cannot remove {count}x {item.itemName} from stack of {item.amount}.");
                return false;
            }
            if (item.amount > count)
            {
                Debug.Log($"Removing {count}x {item.itemName} from #{index}.");
                item.amount -= count;
                return true;
            }
        }
        
        // Remove item completely.
        Debug.Log($"Removing {(item.stackable ? $"all {item.amount}x " : "")}{item.itemName} at #{index}.");
        _items.RemoveAt(index);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And now your `Player` class has the following for inventory:

```
// inventory, limited to 3 slots
readonly Inventory playerInventory = new(3);

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    // Check if there's an item to collect.
    if (collision.GetComponent<GroundItem>()?.item is ItemObject item)
    {
        if (playerInventory.TryAddItem(item))
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
    }
    // Check other collision types, like traps and such...
    else if (collision.GetComponent<GroundTrap>() is GroundTrap trap)
    {
        // process trap
    }
}
```

This makes it simpler to extend the functionality and operation of the `Inventory` class without further cluttering the `Player` class. You can even add multiple attached inventories - bags in the `Player`'s inventory can have inventories of their own and so on.